# Non correct output of bibliography entries after highlighting an author

Tags: bibtex, formatting, moderncv, bold

Following the instructions provided by gogolin in this [topic][1] I encountered some problems in the output of my bibliography:

Instead of getting

**Doe J.**, Smith A., ...

it is displayed

**Doe**, **J.** Smith, A. ...

So it seems that the highlighting function is working but the way the records are displayed is totally messed up.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv/moderncv}        

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage{pdfpages/pdfpages}
\usepackage{moderntimeline/moderntimeline}
\tlmaxdates{2003}{2016}                            
\usepackage{xpatch/xpatch}

\usepackage[url=true,
    backend=bibtex,                                  
    style=authoryear,
    firstinits=true,
    doi=false,  
    isbn=false,
    backref=false,
    dashed=false,                                   
    maxnames=30,                               
    sorting=ydnt,
    mincitenames=2,
    maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}   

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\usepackage{substr}

% MAKE BOLD A SPECIFIC AUTHOR

\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \edef\tempname{{#1}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}
\makeauthorbold{Doe}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addbibresource{pub1.bib}                   

\input{biblatex_modifications/standard_modification.tex}        

\newcommand{\cvreferencecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}



\newcommand{\cvreference}[8]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{\href{mailto:#6}{\nolinkurl{#6}}}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7\newline}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\mobilephonesymbol~#8}}

%-------------------Personal Data for CV title-----------------------------------------------------------

\name{John}{Doe}

\address{my street}{my city}{a place}




\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\input{cvitem_modifications/cvitem_modified} 
\nocite{*}                                         
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Publications}]


\input{cvitem_modifications/cvitem_moderncvclassic} 

\end{document}
```

The code responsible of highlighting is below MAKE BOLD A SPECIFIC AUTHOR

The pub1 file is

```
@article{doe2015,
    Author = {Doe, John and  Kobayashi, Kazuto and Mannaioni, Guido},
    Journal = {Eur J Neurosci},
    Journal-Full = {The European journal of neuroscience},
    Keywords = {dopaminergic neurons; hcn channels; parkinson's disease; patch clamp; th-gfp mice},
    Month = {Sep},
    Pst = {aheadofprint},
    Title = {Cheating at University},
    Year = {2015}}

@article{doe2013,
    Author = {Doe, John and Mannaioni, Guido},
    Journal = {Nature},
    Journal-Full = {Nature},
    Keywords = {dopaminergic neurons; hcn channels; parkinson's disease; patch clamp; th-gfp mice},
    Month = {Sep},
    Pst = {aheadofprint},
    Title = {Parkinson's disease, no hope},
    Year = {2013}}
```

Thank you for the attention and forgive me if I wasn't clear about my problem

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of MiKTeX and `moderncv` I can compile the following MWE without problems.  As you can see I had to change some things, for example I commented the `\input` commands (because we do not have the inputted files!). I also commented some packages whic are not used in the given example.

Please run the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe2015,
  Author = {Doe, John and  Kobayashi, Kazuto and Mannaioni, Guido},
  Journal = {Eur J Neurosci},
  Journal-Full = {The European journal of neuroscience},
  Keywords = {dopaminergic neurons; hcn channels; parkinson's disease; patch clamp; th-gfp mice},
  Month = {Sep},
  Pst = {aheadofprint},
  Title = {Cheating at University},
  Year = {2015},
}
@article{doe2013,
  Author = {Doe, John and Mannaioni, Guido},
  Journal = {Nature},
  Journal-Full = {Nature},
  Keywords = {dopaminergic neurons; hcn channels; parkinson's disease; patch clamp; th-gfp mice},
  Month = {Sep},
  Pst = {aheadofprint},
  Title = {Parkinson's disease, no hope},
  Year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\listfiles % creates list of used packages and versions in log file
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{moderntimeline}
%\tlmaxdates{2003}{2016}                            
%\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[%
  url=true,
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
% firstinits=true,
  doi=false,  
  isbn=false,
  backref=false,
  dashed=false,                                   
  maxnames=30,                               
  sorting=ydnt,
  mincitenames=2,
  maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}   

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\usepackage{substr}

% MAKE BOLD A SPECIFIC AUTHOR

\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \edef\tempname{{#1}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}
\makeauthorbold{Doe}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}                   

%\input{biblatex_modifications/standard_modification.tex}        

\newcommand{\cvreferencecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\cvreference}[8]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{\href{mailto:#6}{\nolinkurl{#6}}}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7\newline}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\mobilephonesymbol~#8}}

%-------------------Personal Data for CV title--------------------------
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{my street}{my city}{a place}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
%\input{cvitem_modifications/cvitem_modified} 
\nocite{*}                                         
\printbibliography[%
% type=article,
  title={Journal Publications}
]


%\input{cvitem_modifications/cvitem_moderncvclassic} 

\end{document}
```

and check the result you get. My result is:

[image: My result is]

As you can see the author is bold, the other part is as supposed to be.

Please compare the following list of used packages and versions with the list in your log file. It could be you have to update your system. If there are no differences it seems the error is hidden in the inputted files ...

List created by `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter compatibility patches
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
moderncvheadi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 1
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: blue
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
biblatex.sty    2015/12/22 v3.2 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2015/12/22 v3.2 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  blx-dm.def
authoryear.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.bbx    2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.cbx    2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 english.lbx    2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  269243.bbl
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
  269243.out
  269243.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```